# how to run two separate asynchronous tasks run separately?

Tags: android

In my application I have two button clicks and in both button clicks there are two different Asynchronous tasks are running ,and my problem is when i click button 1 and first asynchronous task is running mean while its running i clicked second button and second asynchronous task also started but in background till the first asynchronous task is completed  the second asynchronous task is not starting ?

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long arg3) {
if(position==1)
           {

              Asynchronoustask1();

           }

            if(position==2)
            {

              Asynchronoustask2();
            }
}
```

Comment: please post the code for you asynchronous tasks

Comment: Are your sure its the position ==2,  do a log to check if that event is called or not

Answer (score 5):

If your implementation for `AsyncTask` is correct, then the possible reason for this behaviour is because the default `executor` for `AsyncTasks` is `SERIAL_EXECUTOR`.

To run multiple `AsyncTask`   instances in parallel (not serially.. no one after other). execute them as follows:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
    outstandingTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
} else {
    outstandingTask.execute();
}
```

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#):

> When first introduced, `AsyncTask` were executed serially on a single
>   background thread. Starting with `DONUT`, this was changed to a pool of
>   threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with
>   `HONEYCOMB`, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common
>   application errors caused by parallel execution.
>
> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke
>   `executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent. Executor, Object[])` with
>   `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple Options to run `asyncrhonously` Either you can use two `AsyncTask` which contains a method called `doInBackground()` for your use. Or simple you can use two `threads`.

Eg: `Thread`

```
Thread thread = new Thread()
{
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        while(true) {
           // your code
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
};

thread.start();
```

If you want any `delay` Use `Handler`.

Or

You need to do any `UI` Operations you should use `RunOnUIThread()`

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous task always run in background.It will not disturb the any process.Might be your first Asynchronous task holding some resources and that one also using for second one.So its waiting for the resource.

Please have look @ your code carefully or paste your code..